# Return current time from different timezones

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

I'm using Script Editor in macOS to create scripts that will return the current time for different timezones in the United States. I have it working, however, it is also returning the date which I don't need. This is my first real JavaScript project, and everything else I've found in my searches seems to include the date. I'm using separate scripts for each timezone, but here's an example of what I have to show the current time in the Eastern timezone:

`new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })`

I know there are a lot of posts here about timezones and converting them, I just couldn't find anything straightforward that did not include the date.

Comment: Just put your code into a variable and then you can use the [JS Date Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) to take the hours, minutes and seconds and put them into a variable together, so that you have one variable to display the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [moment](https://momentjs.com/) module, in particular, [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

With those modules, it is easy to pass time zones:

```
let d = moment(new Date());
d.tz("America/New_York");
d.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) to return just the time part of the datetime.

```js
const eastern = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' });
console.log(eastern);
```